# HPC: Are launched nodes the clones of interface node?

Tags: io, hpc

When a SLURM batch job which requests several nodes is submitted, do launched nodes are clones of interface computer? Do they copy everything in interface computer? Here, the interface computer is the one which I ssh to, store files on and submit jobs from.

Especially, in IO context, suppose that I read data from text files named as data_N.dat where N is the process rank. In other words, each process (node) reads its own unique file. When I submit a SLURM job, do all these files get copied to launched nodes? Or nodes read input files line by line from interface computer?

Answer (score 0):

Each node act as if you just connected via ssh from the interface.

If there isn't a shared filesystem (that are very common on HPC clusters but not provided by SLURM) or outside shared folders, you'll want to copy them via ssh/a shared folder.

You could just start an interactive task in SLURM and check if you can access your files.